# How match index of one word to index of all other words in list return only if all index match of first word in other any word?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, list, match

I am trying to solve a puzzle in python and the puzzle says :

```
Two words “interlock” if taking alternating letters from each forms a 
new word. For example, “shoe” and “cold” interlock to form “schooled. 
interlocks word's characters can be random position ex : "iam" can be
 "mia" now if "iam" and  "boy” ==> combined word  cab be yobmia
```

so if i have a list :

```
a=["shoe","cold","schooled","any","boy","hair","iahroby","i","yani"]
```

in this list :

`schooled` => conbination of  `shoe` + `cold`

`iahroby` => cobination of  `hair`+ `boy`

`yani` =>    combination of `any` + `i`

so my paper-algorithm what i wrote is :

[image]

according to that algorithm i am able to perform till step 2 but after step two how i match each index of one word with each other index of word , i could do this with zip module , finditer or nested loop but the thing is i don't have to match one same postion index like "iam"=="iam" , index can be in random position like "iam" will be "mia"  , so how i can perform this problem ?

what i tried is buggy code and not working yet , i am sharing still

```
a=["shoe","cold","schooled","any","s","pre","our","uorpre"]




    def hello(ae):
        for i in ae:
            yield i

    ar=hello(a)

    aq=list(ar.__next__())



    def check(tr):
        for i in tr:
            for j in i:
                if j in aq:
                    ??

    check(a)
```

Since the pattern is repeating so I was trying to implement recursive approach, but that is not working.

Comment: Your examples "iahroby" and "yani" are wrong. You should read the puzzle more carefully.

Comment: @StefanPochmann yes i know puzzle , but i made it little complex by myself. this is my custom puzzle you can say.

Comment: Um... then why do you say you're trying to solve that puzzle when you really aren't? And how are we supposed to help with your custom puzzle when we don't know what it is because you're not telling us?

Comment: @StefanPochmann i already shown my paper algo and example very clear , i explained "iam" can be "mia" , please read

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul If I get it right, I think you want to have something like to check for anagram??

Comment: @AmitYadav this is not anagram bro :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Order is ignored

It looks like you don't care about letter positions. In that case, you only need to check if the letters from `word1` and `word2` sum up to the letters from `goal`. Since you don't care about position, it's enough to sort the letters:

```
words = ["shoe","cold","schooled","any","s","pre","our","uorpre"]

for goal in words:
    lg = len(goal)
    goal_letters = sorted(goal)
    for word1 in words:
        l1 = len(word1)
        if lg > l1:
            for word2 in words:
                if word2 > word1 and len(word2) == lg - l1:
                    if sorted(word1 + word2) == goal_letters:
                        print('%s + %s = %s' % (word1, word2, goal))
```

It outputs:

```
cold + shoe = schooled
boy + hair = iahroby
any + i = yani
```

It's not efficient but it works fine for your examples.

## Order is taken into account

If order is taken into account, you can get split the word with `::2` and `1::2` and check if those are known words (thanks to @StefanPochmann):

```
words = set(["shoe", "cold", "schooled", "any", "boy", "hair", "iahroby", "i", "yani"])

for goal in words:
    word1 = goal[::2]
    word2 = goal[1::2]
    if word1 in words and word2 in words:
      print('%s * %s = %s' % (word1, word2, goal))
# shoe * cold = schooled
```

It outputs:

```
shoe * cold = schooled
```

Comment: For "order is taken into account" you'd better use the normal solution of testing whether `goal[::2]` and `goal[1::2]` are both in the set of words. Much more efficient and can handle odd-length goal words as well.

Comment: but your second solution doesn't pass all test cases :p

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul which one?

Comment: sir , second one :) as it print only shoe * cold = schooled not the other words

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul well yes, because the other words aren't sorted correctly. That's the difference between the two methods.